# How to pass a shell script that lives in a variable, to a function

Tags: python

I am trying to pass a sequence of shell script commands to a python function.

I used to call the script.sh file inside subprocess, but now I would like to have the script itself in the function, so I don't have to worry about the trailing script.

oversimplified example to give an idea:

```
def myfunc()
    script = "ls -la; cd /; ls -la"
    runscript_output = subprocess.call(script)
    print runscript_output
```

Is this the correct way to do so?

I saw some examples where the shell commands were wrapped in EOF wrappers; although I am not really sure why.

Comment: Re: the "EOF wrappers", that probably was a different language -- Python doesn't support heredocs.

Comment: The EOF wrappers were probably bash redirection. You should make your function accept a command as an argument so you could use it elsewhere.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: the example was using it in a string running in a python function; something like string= "cat << 'EOF' >>" or something like that; I believe that is shell script syntax

Comment: Yes, heredocs are shell syntax, but other languages (including Ruby) also have that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use `shell=True` in this use case. Also, I'd strongly suggest making your script text constant, and pushing any variable substitutions as separate arguments:

```
script_text=r'''
ls -la
cd "$1" || exit
ls -la
'''

# for /bin/sh
def myfunc_sh():
    runscript_output = subprocess.check_output(
        [script_text,       # /bin/sh script text here
         '/'],              # add values for $1 and on as list elements
        shell=True)
    print runscript_output

# for /bin/bash
def myfunc_bash():
    runscript_output = subprocess.check_output(
        ['bash',            # interpreter to run
         '-c', script_text, # script to invoke
         '_',               # value for $0
         '/'])              # add values for $1 and on as extra list elements here
    print runscript_output
```

Following this practice -- keeping the content passed to the shell as script text constant -- avoids opening you up to shell injection vulnerabilities, wherein data is parsed as code.

Comment: Much appreciated Charles; this is mostly code ran locally in my parsing suite; I grab a ton of logs from the output of a spectrometer and ran operations on them, so I would say that the risk of injection of malicious code is pretty low. Giving it a try!

Comment: Something need not be intentionally malicious to throw a wrench in the works. At one of my former employers, we lost multiple TB of billing data after a buffer overflow threw a stream of random garbage including a whitespace-surrounded asterisk into a filename, and a poorly-written script (wherein its author had left out some otherwise-necessary quotes) tried to delete that file.

Comment: By the way -- note that anything you run with `shell=True` will be invoked with `/bin/sh`, not `bash` or `ksh` or whatnot. Thus, you might instead consider something like `['bash', '-c', script_text, '-s'] + argument_list`, if you want to write your code to be executed by a more capable shell.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I am writing for bash, so I have to change it to the example in the comment.

Comment: Actually -- using `-s` isn't strictly necessary with `-c`; one can simply provide an explicit placeholder for `$0`, such as `_`, and place additional positional arguments (for `$1` and so on) after. I've amended the answer to do so here.

Comment: Thanks again Charles; btw what is the difference of using 3 single quote instead of 2 with the semicolon between commands? are they equivalent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87939/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-newbiez).